# ASP.Net MVC - How to get collection of dropdownlists in controller with selected values

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4

I have an unordered list with multiple list items where in each one they have a checkbox and a dropdownlist.

I want to get at the selected dropdown value for each dropdown that corresponds to a checkbox that was checked.

I can easily get at the checkboxes that were checked by having a controller parameter of **int[] checkboxes**. This gives the value of every checkbox that was checked.

Now, how can I get the selected value of the dropdowns that are next to these checked checkboxes.

Will I have to use javascript to capture the selected values and pass it to the controller?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to work with more complex model than just `int[]` in a controller:

```
public class CheckedListModel
{
    public bool IsChecked { get; set; }

    public int SelectedValue { get; set; }

    public SelectList Items { get; set; }
}
```

A sample view to render a list of such models:

```
@model CheckedListModel[]

@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    <ul>
        @for (int i = 0; i < Model.Length; i++)
        {
            <li>
                @Html.CheckBoxFor(m => m[i].IsChecked)
                @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m[i].SelectedValue, Model[i].Items)
            </li>
        }
    </ul>
    <input type="submit" value="Save"/>
}
```

And the controller:

```
    [HttpGet]
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View(new CheckedListModel[]
            {
                //Sample data
                new CheckedListModel{Items = new SelectList(new []
                    {
                        new SelectListItem{Text = "Text 1", Value="1"},
                        new SelectListItem{Text = "Text 2", Value="2"},
                        new SelectListItem{Text = "Text 3", Value="3"},
                    }, "Value", "Text")},
                new CheckedListModel{Items = new SelectList(new []
                    {
                        new SelectListItem{Text = "Text 5", Value="5"},
                        new SelectListItem{Text = "Text 6", Value="6"},
                    }, "Value", "Text")},
            });
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Index(CheckedListModel[] models)
    {
        IEnumerable<CheckedListModel> checkedItems = models.Where(m => m.IsChecked);
        //Rest of the code
    }
```